# Target date funds - glide path quantitative foundations?

Tags: asset-allocation

Are there any introductions that show an academic proof or quantitative process for determining the proper asset allocations for a glide-path in a target date fund?

I've been trying to find something on the topic but it looks like a bunch of arbitrary asset allocations based on some made up "risk aversion" measure.